# I cannot download MySQL ConnectorJ with ansible anymore

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have a task that looks like this:

```
- name: Download {{ mysql_connector_download_url }}
  ansible.builtin.get_url:
    url: '{{ mysql_connector_download_url }}'
    dest: '{{ mysql_connector_download_dir }}/{{ mysql_connector_download_file }}'
  register: jdbc_driver
```

where `mysql_connector_download_url` expands to `https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.tar.gz`

This has worked for quite a while but for some reason it does not anymore and the error I get is this:

```
    "msg": "Request failed",
    "response": "HTTP Error 403: Forbidden",
    "status_code": 403,
    "url": "https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.tar.gz"
```

The odd thing is that I can type `wget` and the same URL on the target machine and that works fine, it is only through ansible this download fails.

I was thinking that perhaps cookies are involved but if that was the case, should not the `wget` fail as well?

Comment: It's probably a matter of user agent. What if you try wget with User-Agent ansible-httpget?

Comment: So I tried `wget -U "ansible-httpget" https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.tar.gz` on the target and that worked just fine. :-(

Comment: This is probably related to the 302 redirection. Pointing to the redirected url (i.e. https://cdn.mysql.com//Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.tar.gz) fixes the issue. It should work with the redirection though...

Comment: I was thinking about that possibility but I had no idea as to how to get the redirected URL. Thank you for that suggestion -- I will try it out presently

Comment: `I had no idea as to how to get the redirected URL` <= one solution is to just read the wget output when you download manually from the original uri.

Comment: Ah, I've never payed much attention to that output. Bad choice. Live and learn. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the file is available but hidden behind a a redirection it turned out that the easiest way is to look at the output from `wget` to get the file's real location and download it from there.

In this case redirects `https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads…` to `https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads…` and passing that last URL to Ansible was successful.

This might of course change in the future but this solution solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the request header User-Agent. It will return 403 if using the header as "User-Agent":"ansible-httpget", but it will work if set header as "User-Agent":"curl/7.29.0".

For getting the 302 redirected uri, you can take a look at this Github comments: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27293#issuecomment-518389800.